# nsdate give null value

Tags: iphone, null, nsdate

Hi at all I want to parsing a date from XML with this format:

2012/05/25 02:37

```
- (void) compareDate:(NSString *)dataUno secondaData:(NSString *) dataDue {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];

    NSDate *dt1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:dataUno];
    NSDate *dt2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:dataDue];

    NSLog(@"dt1: %@ dt2: %@", dt2, dt1);
}
```

but when I try to print the date I get a null value, where is the error?

kikko088

Comment: What calendar has 37 months???

Comment: Or 37 days in a 29th month...

Comment: the number is random number...now I change it but in xml are correct, excuse me, I edit the question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date formatter's format string `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"` doesn't match your date format. Actually, `"2012/37/29 02:37"` isn't a date under any format, but I assume the 37 is a typo and that's supposed to be the month.

Try this:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"];
```

Comment: the number are random but in xml are correct for example 2012/03/25, excude me for the issue, I edit now the question

Comment: I try it but is the same...always null

Comment: Are you sure the strings aren't null? Try logging them right before you use the date formatter.

Comment: solved...I have a wrong character on the string, now work perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your input string doesn't match the format you specified (it uses "/" instead of "-"), so it's returning NULL.